# Improve performance of component with computationally heavy render function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Consider the following component:

```
class Container extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { dataArr: props.dataArr };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.createTextFields()}
      </div>
    );
  }

  createTextFields = () => this.state.dataArr.map((data, index) =>
    <TextField 
      key={index}
      value={data}
      onChange={newData => this.handleTextFieldChange(index, newData)}
    />;

  handleTextFieldChange = (index, newData) => {
    const newDataArr = this.state.dataArr.splice();
    newDataArr[index] = newData;
    this.setState({ dataArr: newDataArr });
  }
}
```

Everytime you write in any of the text fields, the state `dataArr` is replaced (not mutated), the render method is called and we loop through and map all elements in in the array. If `dataArr` is very large and we write very fast (holding down a key) this is a very computationally heavy operation, leading to stuttering, lag and sometimes a complete lockdown.

This is how I've always written components that creates their own content from props, and it's not until recently that I've discovered its flaws. Are there other ways of doing this, some design patterns I've missed out on or "hacks" that can improve on the performance of components like these?

Comment: well you could trigger the `handleTextFieldChange()` on a different `event`, such as `onBlur` ... or you could check if a key is still being pressed before triggering a complete rerender with `setState`

Comment: I think this will help you: https://medium.com/@esamatti/react-js-pure-render-performance-anti-pattern-fb88c101332f

Comment: So after reading the above link. The `newData => this.handleTextField(..)` is creating a new function instance every time the component is rendered. That means React can not tell that it should shadow the <textField> as it appears to be mutating after each render. You need to bind the function to event like this `onChange=this.handleTextFieldChange` so that the same function reference is used each time. I'm not a React guy. So forgive me if I'm wrong. That's why I didn't post this as an answer.